# SFTLinksPermissions printing on emails in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a user who is looking to print an email, but every time she goes to do it Outlook adds about a dozen lines of permissions tags to the header.  I haven't been able to find any settings or preferences relating to this; does anyone know how to disable it?

Example:

**Sent:**    (Date)

**Subject:** (Subject)

**SFTLinksPermissions:**    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`
`<LinksPermissions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001XMLSchema">`
`<NotifyOwner>false</NotifyOwner>`
`<CanAccessAnonymously>false</CanAccessAnonymously>`
`<CanInvite>true</CanInvite>`
`<CanDownload>true</CanDownload>`
`<CanUploadChanges>true</CanUploadChanges>`
`<CanManipulate>false</CanManipulate>`
`<InheritsFromParent>false</InheritsFromParent>`
`<ExpiryDate xsi:nil="true" />`
`</LinksPermissions>`

Comment: Can you [edit] and give an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is a side effect of having the Workshare plugin installed in Outlook. I've heard there is a patch you can apply or a setting you can change to make it go away, but I'm not aware of the details.